# Conditional AJAX in Ruby On Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am looking to trigger an AJAX action depending on the location/page of the user. I built the following:

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf('users/stream') >= 0) {
  alert("Condition 1 is met")
  $('#invite_to_video').html("<%= j render partial: 'messages/contact_ir_video', :locals => {:message => Message.new}  %>");
} else {
  alert("Condition 2 is met")
  $("#comments").html("<%= j render partial: '@message.comments' %>");
}
```

When I simply try the `if` condition with the `alert`, it works well and `Condition 1 is met` is displayed.

However when I add the partial loading instructions I get the following:

> ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial messages/*@message.comments, application/*@message.comments with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:...

Although, it should only be condition 1 that triggers.

What would be the best way to do such conditional jQuery?

Comment: Try removing the single quotes for the arguments of render

Comment: Nice, you can answer and accept your own solution ;)

Comment: Actually mine was not working, yours worked.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, do you know by any chance how to display a quick notice when an AJAX call is completed? I tried the following:           respond_to do |format|
            flash.now[:notice] = "The message was sent."
            format.js {render :layout => false}
          end

But nothing happens

Comment: That's an interesting question, you can create a new one with enough details to try to replicate the behavior you're seeing